# Calculate $\int \frac{x^{\:}}{\sqrt{x^4+3}}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, radicals

How to calculate

$$\int \frac{x^{\:}}{\sqrt{x^4+3}}\ dx$$

Comment: **Hint:**

What about the sustitution $x^2=\sqrt{3}\tan t$?

Comment: The trick here is reducing to $$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{s^2+1}}\,ds$$

Comment: (assuming the "surface-integral" is just a bad choice of tag)

Comment: @SophieAgnesi The first edit after the question was put on hold gets it into [reopen review queue](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/645688), see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/should-i-avoid-minor-edit-of-a-question-which-was-put-on-hold/16821#16821) (if it is within 5 days). For this reason I think that if a question is on hold, we should avoid minor edits. An edit which addresses all reasons why the post was put on hold is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

Try to show what you think will work or what you've tried next time you ask a question.
$$\int \frac{x^{\:}}{\sqrt{x^4+3}}dx$$
$$u=x^2\Rightarrow du=2x~dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u^2+3}}du$$
Substituting the integral now
$$u=\sqrt{3}\tan v\Rightarrow du=\sqrt{3}\sec^2dv$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\int\dfrac{\sec^2v}{\sqrt{3\tan^2v+3}}dv$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\int\dfrac{\sec^2v}{\sec^2v\sqrt{3}}dv$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\int \sec(v)~dv$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\ln(\tan v+\sec v)$$
Now we substitute $v$ back in
$$=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\ln
\left(\tan \left(\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x^2\right)\right)+\sec \left(\arctan\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}x^2\right)\right)\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\ln\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{x^4}{3}+1}+\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C$$
$$=\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{3}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{x^4+3}{3}}\right)}{2}+C$$
$$=\dfrac{\ln\left(\dfrac{x^2+\sqrt{x^4+3}}{\sqrt{3}}\right)}{2}+C$$
$$=\dfrac{\ln\left(x^2+\sqrt{x^4+3}\right)-\dfrac{\ln3}{2}}{2}+C$$
$$=\dfrac{2\ln\left(x^2+\sqrt{x^4+3}\right)-\ln3}{4}+C$$